# Charset issues with embedded c++ software

Tags: character-encoding

I'm working on a EDK project for Xilinx Spartan 6 fpga.
There is a microprocessor system with Microblaze microprocessor implemented in FPGA.

It has a graphical pcore with its own memory space for displaying the text specified in software code executed by Microblaze.
Associated ASCII table has 256 characters.

Software fetches the text by RS232 interface. Everything is okay when displaying English text (0-127) cause English characters are the same in quite any charset. But when trying to display Russian, my software cannot associate appropriate ASCII codes with these symbols.

How should I parse text from rs232 to fit 0-255 ASCII intervals?

Comment: What is the format of the text coming over the RS232 interface?  ASCII and extended ASCII can't display Russian to my knowledge.  Codepages are a Windows thing.  If the software isn't giving you UTF8/16/32, then it isn't Russian.

Comment: Also, what are the options for displaying the text?  If that's not UTF compatable, then you can't display Russian anyway.

Comment: @MooingDuck The text is coming in RAW text format, no extra protocol over RS232 is used. I'm just sending a sequence of characters from source and parse it in embedded target system.
The pcore for displaying text is developed by myself. I manually organized FPGA block RAMs to be a text memory (e.g. 80x40 text mode in old DOS systems). I also organized another amount of BRAMs to be a font ROM an to store 256 characters images of 8x16 console font (made from cyrillic PSF font file). in order to show character on a screen I only need to set a byte of text memory with Microblaze processor.

Comment: All text has a format.  The only format you've mentioned so far is ASCII, which is only defined for 0-127.  Since you say it's 0-255, I must assume your input is using a Windows Codepage for the other 128, (Mark says code page 1251, Cyrilic)  I would also assume that your output is not matching whatever the codepage of the input is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know the character encoding used by your source - RS232 is just a method for moving the bits, it doesn't specify any encoding. Is the source Windows for example? If so, the characters might be either Unicode (UTF-8) or [code page 1251](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251). Once you know this encoding you'll need to translate each character, probably using a lookup table of 256 bytes. If the source uses multiple bytes for some characters as UTF-8 does, you'll first need to assemble the bytes into a character code before you can do the lookup.

Comment: It's also possible (though unlikely) to be UTF-16.  Also, if the _output_ function takes the same as the input, he doesn't have to do a lookup.

Comment: @MooingDuck, you're right it could be UTF-16, but if it was I'd expect that to have presented itself already with the ASCII output. I also assume that a mapping is needed, otherwise this question wouldn't have been asked.

Comment: @Mark Ransom
I'd like to be independent from source OS. It could be Windows, Mac or Linux. Don't know exactly what kind of encoding is used, but when tested with English characters everything worked like a charm in any OS.
How can I determine the charset I need to transfer information from source? Should I standartize it manually between source OSes?

Comment: @AndreyPesoshin, you can't be independent of source OS because the extended characters depend on the OS and settings. The English ASCII characters are standardized and work everywhere, as you have noticed, but the same is not true of the Russian characters. Post some text and a hex dump of it in your question, maybe we can figure it out for you.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thank you, will do it shortly

Comment: @MarkRansom I tried sending data from various OS and you are right - everything instead of English characters (0-127) is sent as various sequences of bytes. I think the best way is to encode characters into the only acceptable 8-bit encoding format (like cp1251) on source system. So in this way embedded code can be independent of source native character encoding. Thank you and MooingDuck for help!